# button_to using remote: true to js file jquery in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code in a file show.js.erb

```
$("#id4").html("<%= j render(partial: 'current_user_show') %>");
```

this is rendering the _current_user_show.html.erb partial.

I want to add a condition by that if the id is not `id4`, and say another id eg `id7` that the function will go through that id and render a different partial. How can I do that please?

I have gone through a few ways to try and get a different partial to render according to the id but I am not that good with javascript or jquery and I am not exactly sure what my remote true is sending back for me to set what conditions and statement to render.

**EDITED for clarity**

Path of the show.js.erb relative to the project root is views/users/show.js.erb where the root is /views/static_pages/home. When browsing to a users profile at localhost:3000/users/:id the views/users/show.html.erb file is rendered. It is there I want to be able to use ajax to bring up that users microposts with a onclick (which is already working) but need to alter the show.js.erb as it is currently getting the current_user microposts with a onclick of #id `id4` where as just a standard users profile has a #id `id7`, so in that file, or some other way, I need to be able to use ajax to get the users @micrposts. The current_user goes through the same action as just a standard user being that of users#show but because of the path user_path(current_user) and user_path(@user) on the button_to it renders out the corresponding microposts.

**EDIT here is a example** I wanted to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504372/ruby-on-rails-render-a-partial-in-another-view-via-jquery-ajax) but I am not sure what to put as my if() and else if() condition for either ajax call?

Comment: sir please have a look at my trouble and answer me too ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325444/please-tell-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-file-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment71803966_42325444

Comment: mate I cannot comment on your post, I need more than 50 reputations.

Comment: Can you paste in the path of your `show.js.erb` file, relative to the project root?

Comment: If your objective is to show a different partial for each user id, I would argue that perhaps you need a different approach, unless there are only ever going to be a couple of different user ids. You need to show the code that is rendering the button_to and the relevant controller code that the form posts to.

The rails guides might help you - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @amingilani. Yes can paste in that. @margo. I want the show action to render each users microposts from the users/show view file with #id `id7`, through ajax. I already have the current_user microposts being rendered on static_pages/Home with #id `id4` with the code i pasted above but need to use the same show.js.erb file to get just the user's microposts on users/show view page. I will try explain a bit better above.

Comment: Answer to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800424/how-to-use-key-value-pairs-in-ajax-call-for-jquery-data-option)